# Analytic solution for integral $(1 - (1 - p)^6) \cdot \cal{N}$?

Tags: integration

Is it possible to calculate this integral analytically?

$$\int^\infty_{-\infty} (1 - (1 - \Phi(x))^6) \cdot e^{-\frac{1}{2}(\frac{x - \mu}{\sigma})^2}dx$$

Where $\Phi$ is either:

1. [Normal CDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_distribution#Cumulative_distribution_function)
2. [Inverse logit](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logit)

Both of those sigmoidal functions could be used in my application; I strongly prefer solution for logit, which I currently use; but if the integral is not tractable analytically for logit, I can switch to Normal CDF.

---

<sub>Background (not needed for the question, just the motivation behind this): I have a function $F(p) = (1 - (1 - p)^6)$ which tells probability of occurence based on probability $p$; and then, from regression similar to logistic, I have an estimate (a normal distribution) for $p$ on a logit scale, i.e. $\Phi^{-1}(p) = x \sim \cal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2)$</sub>

I want to estimate the mean of $F(p)$, so for this I need the integral. Currently I solve it by sampling 100000 samples out of the normal distribution but that's not very smart solution :-)

Comment: I doubt there's a closed form for the integral.

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk what do you mean by "closed form"?

Comment: No hope even if $\mu=0$